# "substitute" in active/passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

How come the following sentences have the same meaning when they have different voices?

> I can be substituted for John. (Passive)
>
> I can substitute for John. (Active)

They both mean "I can replace John."

Comment: Is your question "How is it possible for two different sentences to have the same meaning?"?  Because this is extremely common - in fact, any sentence could be expressed differently without losing the meaning.

Comment: @BillJ That is a different scenario. The equivalent scenario would be *I can substitute for John / John can be substituted for by me*. The querent is asking why, say, both *the window broke* and *the window was broken* can have the same meaning.

Comment: 'Substitute' is an ergative verb. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb): 'In linguistics, an ergative verb is a verb that can be either transitive or intransitive, and whose subject when intransitive corresponds to its direct object when transitive.' Thus 'The water boiled' < ... > '[I] boiled the water.' The passive transformation is also available for the transitive usage: 'The water was boiled.' // 'Substitute' is even more complicated, as 'He was substituted by John' (taken off) and 'He was substituted for John' (sent on) are both available.